# Is there any helper class that monitor a value for me constantly to triggers an event if value changed?

Tags: c#, timer

Is there some kind of helper provided by the C# language like ChangeMonitor class below that could monitor a change for me?

```
bool errorHappened = false;
...
...
// ChangeMonitor monitors the change of another object for me and run my lambda expression if value changed
var cancellationTokenSource= new CancellationTokenSource();
ChangeMonitor changeMonitor = new ChangeMonitor(errorHappened, () =>
    {
        // Stop my stuffs
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
task.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

What I do currently as a workaround is by using Timer like below.

```
System.Timers.Timer checkErrorTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
checkErrorTimer.Elapsed += (i, j) =>
    {
        if (errorHappened)
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    };
checkErrorTimer.Start();
```

Comment: There is nothing like that in .Net Framework (clearly C# itself does not provide it)... Can you make "errorHappened" implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: errorHappened variable is written by someone else and it is under a library I am using, So I am not allowed to change it at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and given the value returned by a property may be random, based on a calculation, as well as the more typical backing variable, the only two solutions that are close to what you describe would be:

1. **Create a polling class**.  Every x number of ticks it checks the value of a property.  This lets you know the value has changed, at the expense of running a lot (and depending upon the property, this might in fact change the value).
2. **Have your property implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged).** And then subscribe to the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) event. This will do exactly what you want, but you have to have control of the class source code.